# Apache2.2 not running php scripts for virtual host

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Hey guys I have a lamp setup in a virtual-box (running Ubuntu-server 12.04 with apache2.2 and php5.3.10). I have a virtual host file which looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@demosite.com
    ServerName demosite.dev
    ServerAlias www.demosite.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/demosite

    <Directory /var/www/demosite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride ALL
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>  

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bfhosting.log
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

I have an `index.php` file in `/var/www/index.php` and the server runs that file fine. But it's not running any php code that's inside my other website's folder i.e `/var/www/demosite`.

Comment: You have mod php installed and enabled ?

Comment: Yes mod php ins installed and enabled because it works for the other directory. It run php for `/var/www` but not for `/var/www/demosite`. I just don't understand what's wrong with it.